# applyEuler inverse operation

Tags: javascript, three.js

```js
var a = new THREE.Euler( 0, 1, 1.57, 'YXZ' );
var b = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 1 );
var c=b.applyEuler(a);
```

We can get `c` by `b.applyEuler(a)`, but I want an inverse operation with `applyEuler`.

The `c` and `b` are known.

I want to calculate `a`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method you can add to your project to compute the inverse of an `Euler` rotation:

```js
THREE.Euler.prototype.inverse = function () {
    var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    return function inverse() {
        return this.setFromQuaternion( q.setFromEuler( this ).invert() );
    };
}();
```

This method converts the Euler representation to an equivalent quaternion representation, inverts the quaternion, and then converts back.

Note that Euler representations are not unique, and hence the inverse representations are not unique, either.

---

If you have two unit vectors `a` and `b` and you want to know the rotation that maps `a` to `b`, then you can use

```
var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( a, b );
```

`a` and `b` must have length 1, and you can make them so by using the `Vector3.normalize()` method.

three.js r.84